# Obtaining high resolution graphics from a package for publication

Tags: r, image, graphics

I am using an "R" package "ropls"(https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/manuals/ropls/man/ropls.pdf)

I am trying to get the graphics from the package in high-resolution for publication. However, I had no luck so far. It seems like I cannot modify the graphs produced by the package.

Here is the code:

```
    > source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")                            
    > biocLite("ropls")   #install ropls package
    > library(ropls)
    > data(sacurine)
    > attach(sacurine)
    > sacurine.oplsda <- opls(dataMatrix, sampleMetadata[, "gender"], predI = 1, orthoI = NA)
    > plot(sacurine.oplsda)
    > detach(sacurine)
```

I want to save the "summary" plot produced in high-resolution. I want to obtain the plot in both .tiff and .pdf formats in high-resolution.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is this something to do with **R**? If so, please tag it appropriately. If not, please provide a link to whatever `ropls` is. Thanks.

Comment: Provided more info on my quesiton

Comment: have a look at `?tiff` - it has a `res` argument to control resolution. Similarly `cairo_pdf` has `fallback_resolution` when bitmap is needed

Comment: Try doing something like `p <- plot(...); pdf("output.pdf"); p; dev.off()`. in `?pdf` you can set several options like e.g.output size. Hm tiffs you could extract then with acrobat, it's proprietary software, though.

Comment: Hi I did try both ?tiff and ?pdf, they are still not working. For the argument, p<-plot(...); p; p is showing as NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try outputting the summary file to a pdf using the following

> plot(sacurine.oplsda, typeVc="summary", file.pdfC="Graph")

The output graphs are vector PDFs, and hence can be converted using some other programme from a PDF to a TIFF file, with whatever resolution you want.  I don't know what operating system you are on, but Preview on a Mac will do this for you.  Just open the PDF, and export as a TIFF.  Beware file sizes, though, I converted an 8.2 kB PDF to a 1200 dpi TIFF (hey, you wanted high-resolution!) and it was 282 Mb!